# Jenkins ScriptTrigger plugin stopped working by default

Tags: jenkins

I have a strange behavior by my Jenkins and the [ScriptTrigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScriptTrigger+Plugin) plugin.

I have Jenkins 1.510 with the latest version of this plugin.
I have the trigger setup with a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo test
exit 0
```

The trigger is set to start the build if exit code is 0.

After I restart Jenkins (or just reload configuration), the trigger log shows:

```
...
The expected script execution code is 0
[ERROR] - SEVERE - Polling error null
```

No error is in any of the other logs I looked.

No comes the puzzle - if I trigger the job manually, it will make the plugin for this job only start working properly until the next restart...

Has anyone seen this? Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found to be related to the dependency to xtrigger lib version. I downloaded the sources, updated xtrigger.lib.version to be 0.19 and locally built the plugin (and installed it on my Jenkins). This solved the problem.

Thanks for the help of **Gregory Boissinot** (the author of the plugin), who helped me find this. He will release a formal release for this plugin soon.

Note - the current version is 0.22.

I hope this helps.